# How to slide images from arrayList in android

Tags: android, animation, arraylist, ontouchlistener

I am having an arrayList of Imageurls and want to slide it one by one when user slides image second image should dsplay,I have tried as belo but I only able to change when i touch,It changes on touch,But i want it on slide..So Please tell me what code changes should i make..Thank you

```
package com.epe.smaniquines.ui;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Timer;

import twitter4j.Twitter;
import twitter4j.auth.RequestToken;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager.NameNotFoundException;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.PointF;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.provider.MediaStore.Images;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.text.Spannable;
import android.text.SpannableStringBuilder;
import android.text.style.URLSpan;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.AdapterViewFlipper;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ViewFlipper;

import com.epe.smaniquines.R;
import com.epe.smaniquines.adapter.FlipperAdapter;
import com.epe.smaniquines.adapter.ImageSwipeAdapter;
import com.epe.smaniquines.adapter.SimpleGestureFilter;
import com.epe.smaniquines.backend.AlertDialogManager;
import com.epe.smaniquines.backend.ConnectionDetector;
import com.epe.smaniquines.uc.Menu;
import com.epe.smaniquines.util.Const;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.DisplayImageOptions;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoaderConfiguration;

public class DetailsActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener,
        OnTouchListener {
    private SimpleGestureFilter detector;

    ImageView proImage, ivSave, ivInfo, ivPlay, ivBak, iv_share;
    RelativeLayout rl_botm, rl_option;
    TextView tv_facebuk, tv_twiter, tv_nothanks, tv_email, tv_save, tv_quote;
    String big_img;
    int pos;
    ViewPager viewPager;
    ImageSwipeAdapter adapter;
    private static SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences;
    ArrayList<String> resultArray;
    private DisplayImageOptions options;
    public static ImageLoader imageLoader;
    RelativeLayout rl_info;
    public boolean flag = false;
    Menu menu;
    public boolean flag1 = false;
    boolean isOnClick = false;
    int i = 0;
    String cat_nem;

    File casted_image;
    private int PicPosition;
    private Handler handler = new Handler();
    ProgressDialog pDialog;
    ConnectionDetector cd;
    // Alert Dialog Manager
    AlertDialogManager alert = new AlertDialogManager();

    int mFlipping = 0;
    ViewFlipper viewFlipper;
    Timer timer;
    int flagD = 0;
    String data;
    String shareType;
    File image;
    static String PREFERENCE_NAME = "twitter_oauth";
    static final String PREF_KEY_OAUTH_TOKEN = "oauth_token";
    static final String PREF_KEY_OAUTH_SECRET = "oauth_token_secret";
    static final String PREF_KEY_TWITTER_LOGIN = "isTwitterLogedIn";
    TextView titledetail;
    static final String TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL = "oauth://t4jsample";

    // Twitter oauth urls
    static final String URL_TWITTER_AUTH = "auth_url";
    static final String URL_TWITTER_OAUTH_VERIFIER = "oauth_verifier";
    static final String URL_TWITTER_OAUTH_TOKEN = "oauth_token";
    public static String PACKAGE_NAME;
    static String TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY = "AzFSBq1Od4lYGGcGR0u9GkMIT"; // place

    static String TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET = "MBwdard2Y4l6LT6z219NJ6x8aZ4jyK8JBKZ85usRPcDP8ujwM0"; // place
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    Matrix savedMatrix = new Matrix();
    static final int NONE = 0;
    static final int DRAG = 1;
    static final int ZOOM = 2;
    int mode = NONE;

    // Remember some things for zooming

    PointF start = new PointF();

    PointF mid = new PointF();

    float oldDist = 1f;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);
        PACKAGE_NAME = getApplicationContext().getPackageName();
        initialize();
        cat_nem = getIntent().getStringExtra("cat_name");
        System.out.println(":::::::::::CAt nem:::::::::" + cat_nem);
        titledetail.setText(cat_nem);
        proImage.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
        proImage.setOnTouchListener(this);
        showHashKey(this);
        printKeyHashForThisDevice();
        pos = getIntent().getIntExtra("pos", 0);
        cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());

        // Check if Internet present
        if (!cd.isConnectingToInternet()) {
            // Internet Connection is not present
            alert.showAlertDialog(DetailsActivity.this,
                    "Internet Connection Error",
                    "Please connect to working Internet connection", false);
            // stop executing code by return
            return;
        }

        // Check if twitter keys are set
        if (TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY.trim().length() == 0
                || TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET.trim().length() == 0) {
            // Internet Connection is not present
            alert.showAlertDialog(DetailsActivity.this, "Twitter oAuth tokens",
                    "Please set your twitter oauth tokens first!", false);
            // stop executing code by return
            return;
        }
        mSharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(
                "MyPref", 0);
        /*
         * Intent i = getIntent(); data = i.getStringExtra("data"); shareType =
         * i.getStringExtra("type");
         */

        big_img = getIntent().getStringExtra(Const.TAG_BIG_IMG);
        // imageLoader.displayImage(big_img, proImage, options);

        resultArray = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("array");
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        viewPager.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ImagePagerAdapter adapter = new ImagePagerAdapter();
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(resultArray.indexOf(pos));
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        ivInfo.setOnClickListener(this);
        ivPlay.setOnClickListener(this);
        tv_email.setOnClickListener(this);
        tv_facebuk.setOnClickListener(this);
        tv_nothanks.setOnClickListener(this);
        tv_save.setOnClickListener(this);
        tv_twiter.setOnClickListener(this);
        iv_share.setOnClickListener(this);
        ivBak.setOnClickListener(this);
        tv_quote.setOnClickListener(this);
        proImage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                viewPager.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
        // viewFlipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.flipper);
        /*
         * imageLoader.displayImage(big_img, proImage, options);
         * proImage.postDelayed(swapImage, 1000);
         */
        viewPager.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    if (isOnClick) {
                        if (event.getX() > viewPager.getWidth() / 2) {
                            // go to next
                            i = pos;
                            viewPager.setCurrentItem(resultArray.indexOf(i),
                                    true);
                            i++;
                        } else {
                            viewPager.setCurrentItem(resultArray.indexOf(i),
                                    true);
                            i--;
                            // go to previous
                        }
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

    }

    public void open(View view) {

        Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.setType("*/*");
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Hello test"); // <- String
        Uri screenshotUri = Uri.parse(image.getPath());
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, screenshotUri);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share image using"));
    }

    void initialize() {
        proImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_det);
        ivInfo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_info);
        ivPlay = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_play);
        ivBak = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_back);
        rl_botm = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl_bottom);
        rl_option = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl_options);
        tv_save = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_save);
        tv_email = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_email);
        tv_facebuk = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_facebook);
        tv_nothanks = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_no_thanks);
        tv_twiter = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_twiter);
        rl_option.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        tv_quote = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_qote);

        iv_share = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_share);
        imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
        imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration
                .createDefault(DetailsActivity.this));
        rl_info = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl_info);
        rl_info.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        resultArray = new ArrayList<String>();
        ivPlay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        titledetail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.titledetail);

        // twitter

        // Login button

    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.iv_share:
            rl_option.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            rl_info.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            if (flag1) {
                rl_option.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                flag1 = false;
            } else {
                rl_option.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                flag1 = true;
            }

            break;

        case R.id.iv_play:
            proImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            AdapterViewFlipper flipper = (AdapterViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.flipper);
            flipper.setAutoStart(true);
            flipper.setAdapter(new FlipperAdapter(DetailsActivity.this,
                    resultArray));
            Animation in = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
                    android.R.anim.slide_in_left);
            Animation out = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
                    android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
            flipper.setAnimation(out);

            ivPlay.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            break;
        case R.id.iv_back:
            finish();
            break;
        case R.id.tv_email:
            rl_option.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,
                    new String[] { "youremail@yahoo.com" });
            email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject");
            email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "message");
            email.setType("message/rfc822");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email,
                    "Choose an Email client :"));
            break;
        case R.id.tv_save:
            save();
            rl_option.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            break;
        case R.id.tv_facebook:

            // facebookShare();
            /*
             * save(); open(v);
             */
            rl_option.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            break;
        case R.id.tv_no_thanks:
            rl_option.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            break;
        case R.id.tv_twiter:
            rl_option.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            // loginToTwitter();
            // new updateTwitterStatus().execute("3sManiquines");

            break;
        case R.id.iv_info:
            rl_info.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            rl_option.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            if (flag) {
                rl_info.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                flag = false;
            } else {
                rl_info.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                flag = true;
            }

            break;
        case R.id.tv_qote:
            rl_option.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            String url = big_img;

            SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder();
            builder.append("Hi Go to product for details:");
            int start = builder.length();
            builder.append(url);
            int end = builder.length();

            builder.setSpan(new URLSpan(url), start, end,
                    Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            i.setType("message/rfc822");
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { "" });
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Quote");
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, builder);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Select application"));
            break;

        }
    }

    public static void showHashKey(Context context) {
        try {

            PackageInfo info = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                    "com.epe.3SManiquines", PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES); // Your
                                                                            // package
                                                                            // name
                                                                            // here
            for (android.content.pm.Signature signature : info.signatures) {
                MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
                md.update(signature.toByteArray());
                Log.v("KeyHash:",
                        Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
            }
        } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        }
    }

    // slide show..!!!

    MediaPlayer introSound, bellSound;
    Runnable swapImage = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            myslideshow();
            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }
    };

    private void myslideshow() {
        PicPosition = resultArray.indexOf(big_img);
        if (PicPosition >= resultArray.size())
            PicPosition = resultArray.indexOf(big_img); // stop
        else
            resultArray.get(PicPosition);// move to the next gallery element.
    }

    //

    // SAVE TO SD CARD..!!
    void save() {
        BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) proImage.getDrawable();
        Bitmap bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();
        File sdCardDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

        File dir = new File(sdCardDirectory.getAbsolutePath()
                + "/3sManiquines/");
        image = new File(sdCardDirectory, "3s_" + System.currentTimeMillis()
                + ".png");
        dir.mkdirs();
        boolean success = false;

        // Encode the file as a PNG image.
        FileOutputStream outStream;
        try {

            outStream = new FileOutputStream(image);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream);
            /* 100 to keep full quality of the image */

            outStream.flush();
            outStream.close();

            success = true;
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (success) {
            addImageToGallery(dir + "", DetailsActivity.this);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image saved with success",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Error during image saving", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }//

    public static void addImageToGallery(final String filePath,
            final Context context) {

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put(Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN, System.currentTimeMillis());
        values.put(Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/png");
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, filePath);

        context.getContentResolver().insert(Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                values);
    }

    // facebook...

    private void printKeyHashForThisDevice() {
        try {
            System.out
                    .println("::::::::::::::::::::HAsh key called:::::::::::::");
            PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(PACKAGE_NAME,
                    PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
            for (android.content.pm.Signature signature : info.signatures) {
                MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
                md.update(signature.toByteArray());

                String keyHash = Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(),
                        Base64.DEFAULT);
                System.out
                        .println(":::::::::::KEy hash:::::::::::::" + keyHash);

                System.out.println("================KeyHash================ "
                        + keyHash);

            }
        } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        float touchPointX = event.getX();
        float touchPointY = event.getY();
        int[] coordinates = new int[2];
        rl_info.getLocationOnScreen(coordinates);
        rl_option.getLocationOnScreen(coordinates);
        if (touchPointX < coordinates[0]
                || touchPointX > coordinates[0] + rl_info.getWidth()
                || touchPointY < coordinates[1]
                || touchPointY > coordinates[1] + rl_info.getHeight())
            rl_info.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        rl_option.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: // first finger down only

            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: // first finger lifted

            /*
             * if (i < resultArray.size()) {
             * imageLoader.displayImage(resultArray.get(i), proImage); i++; }
             */
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP: // second finger lifted

            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN: // second finger down

            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

            break;

        }
        return true;

    }

    //
    private class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return resultArray.size();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
            return view == ((ImageView) object);
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
            Context context = DetailsActivity.this;
            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
            int padding = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(
                    R.dimen.padding_medium);
            imageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
            imageLoader.displayImage(resultArray.get(position), proImage);
            ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);
            return imageView;
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            ((ViewPager) container).removeView((ImageView) object);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: write thread which gets execute after 1 or 2 seconds and pass that click listener there.

Comment: @chet's-No no you are not getting me..I dont want to make an automated slideshow..I want that when user swipe the image next image shoul be loaded

Comment: Then you can go with view pager which works as per your requirements.

Comment: @chet's-will you please help me I have implemented it,But have no idea to use.Plese

Comment: go through this link sample available there, http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html

Comment: I am too close to solve,Please help.!!!

Comment: change ArrayList<String> urls parameter with Arraylist<Integer> arrImages and pass your ArrayList of images to your Adapter object

Comment: But I am displaying images directly from urls using imageLoader..So how can i do ArrayList<integer>?

Comment: @chet's-I have added my new ontouchListener pls tell me what should be the "Drag_threshold" parameter for it?

Comment: Use viewPager as container for image or Implement Gesters Right Left for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want the way ViewPager slide and handles pages , then you have to implement you own view ( Not with ViewPager ).

ViewPager by default slides through the pages on swipe.

If you want to slide on clicking left or right side to the viewpager , then on touch ACTION_UP call 
`viewPager.setCurrentItem( PAGE_NUM , true );`

This will slide to next or previous page and load appropriate image url.

Comment: Dinesh in place of "AGE_NUM" my imageUrl will be there?

Comment: No, it will be an integer pointing to particular index at your image array that you want to show.

Comment: I can only see the first image in imageView which I have displayed..!

Comment: Where are you setting the adapter to the viewPager?

Comment: Right now , What you are seeing is 'proImage' not a page in viewPager. Hide proImage View and add this line after you create the adapter. `viewPager.setAdapter( adapter )`

Comment: I have Edited code as per you told...now image is changed on swipe but effect is not there..and i have to start froma specific postion of arrayList not always from start.So what should i do,.Pls see my edit

Comment: Dinsesh---I am having a list and on click of any item i want to start slide from that position

Answer (score 0):

You can use ViewPager with fragments for each image url.

This way the memory used to draw image will be handled well by viewpager...

More the image reference you keep in memory , more the possibility of the app crashing.

Comment: I have used view pager...wait I am editing my question.Pls see this dinesh

Comment: What is the type of the instance 'viewPager'?  And it would be better if you can share the complete code.

Comment: Dinesh ya..I have shared my xml code ,Adapter and main activity code..Please see and help..Thank you dinesh

Comment: And I want it when user swipes the image..not automated..Sir..Please save me for it